# Scale down (but not up) images using CSS to fit div container in IE9 (max-width: 100% fix)

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-9

I cannot use JS, this should be archived by CSS only. Container (DIV) is auto width (flexible) "table-cell" element.

I'd want to scale image down only when it width is larger than container (user can resize window - that's the reason).

I've used code shown below but it work only on IE7.

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9;
```

I've tried to find any working fix for IE9, but without success.

Comment: adding just `max-width: 100%;` to the img tag doesn't work? test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SAada/) resizing the window. It works for IE7, IE8, Chrome and Firefox, but I can test it in IE9 right now. Anyway, how is IE9 behaving?

Comment: This is the exact situation and problem which I had to solve:
http://jsfiddle.net/SAada/2/

Comment: The style settings you're using fro the image are fine. Check this sample that works for popular browsers incl IE9 - http://jsfiddle.net/cTxYc/ The settings you've specified for the div's are medddling with the settings for the image

Answer (score 6):

Your `max-width` needs to be set to the image size and then `width` to 100% like so:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Of course, this means that your `max-width` must be dynamically set based off the image being loaded, which may not be practical.

Comment: What if I don't know the image size? User can post it without any limitation and it should scale down flexible.

Comment: Then you cannot limit it to a `max-width`, because you won't know the `max-width` that you will allow (unless you are going to just allow a max for all images, regardless.

Comment: So how the mentioned in original question code works for IE7?

Comment: This is a guess (based off memory). I believe IE7 actually does not support `max-width` unless you are running a strict doctype. So it may be interpreting `max-width` as `width`. In IE7 can you make your image grow larger than the image size itself? If so, that is probably what is happening. If that is not the answer, I do not know.

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon this old question while trying to do the exact same thing the OP was trying. I am answering for anyone who may land here. Upon examining http://jsfiddle.net/SAada/2/ mentioned by the OP, I found an interesting solution:

setting

```
height: auto;
```

will ensure that the image will not be stretched / scaled up. At the same time, setting

```
max-width: 100%
```

will ensure that if the parent element width is less than the image width, the image is scaled down.

Thus, the combination that works for me is:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Oh, and after some more search, I discovered that this technique is also used by Bootstrap for responsive images!