# Google Chrome trouble with table that extends over 100%

Tags: css, google-chrome, tablelayout

I have a table that is 100% and 2 cells one 60% and the other 40%
Inside the 60% one there is an image that is over 60%. Most browsers say ok fine and just shrink the 40% one which is just text.

Google Chrome just extends the 60% one thus making the table over 100%.

The correct solution is to just change the widths but I'm working on a CMS system and these are like 'templates' is there a solution maybe through CSS to ask Google Chrome to respect the 100% table width?

Any ideas - maybe a piece of CSS I can pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quite odd really I was browsing through a few of our other sites in the CMS to try this out and a few has a similar layout to this one but they didn't break.

So it might be a bug in google chrome - of course finding a real fix is tricky. However it seems that if you remove the 40% from that first cell then google chrome thinks like the other browsers and just increases the other cell which sorts it all out.

I viewed all the other sites with this layout and all seem fine with this.

Thanks for all your help.

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Ah maybe found the answer - table-layout:fixed as a style

Answer (score 0):

You could try to solve the problem by applying

```
style="width:100%"
```

to the image in the td

Comment: I think this is close to a solution, but refer to this thread: [Scale down (but not up) images using CSS to fit div container in IE9 (max-width: 100% fix)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050056/scale-down-but-not-up-images-using-css-to-fit-div-container-in-ie9-max-width)

Comment: Ah it's a background image and the width has been set to the number of pixels that it is.